# How to send a request to an API running on local host on a server from my computer?

Tags: node.js, http, request, request-promise

Not sure if I am explaining properly in the title, but what I am trying to do is,

I have a server running, the `curl ifconfig.me` returns 28.76.182.213. On that I have an API running on local host which runs on the port 3000.

I usually send requests to that API from the server itself. Basically `curl -v 127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/jhingat`

But now I am trying to send requests to that API, from my local computer. So I created another API, and sent a request promise to the server.

```
  async getJhingat(jhingatID) {
    let resultObject = [];
    let options = {
      uri: 'http://28.76.182.213:3000/api/v1/jhingat',
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
      },
      json: true
    };
    let jhingat = rp (options);
    console.log(jhingat);
    return jhingat;
  }
```

But the request from this function is not going. The `console.log(jhingat)` shows me a lot of stuff, but the logger for my API on the server does not show a request being received. What can be the possible reason?

Comment: Whether `3000` port is open?? So that other network machines can connect??

Comment: What happens if you do `ping 28.76.182.213` from the computer where you're running this program on and trying to connect to that API? Can you prove that that server is reachable?

Comment: @Subburaj Yup thanks. The port is closed. But how can one open the port through the command line?

Comment: What is the environment for your server computer.  Is it a Windows computer that is likely running a local firewall?  If so, you have to configure the Windows firewall to allow requests to port 3000.

Comment: @Tabachi Harada you have to do through by adding `0.0.0.0/32` for that port through your console. If you server is AWS through AWS console you an do it

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right, the server is unreachable too